# Is there a proper term for describing when a person gives up?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, terminology

Ive come across apathy, learned helplessness and "give up itis".

The last of which is exactly what Im looking for, however it seems to invariably involve death.

Is there a psychological term for giving up because a person feels theres no way out? Without it being as severe as killing them

Comment: Maybe not a psychological term, but I'd go with "capitulate".

Comment: Reasons for apathy (or whatever you want to call it) are very wide-ranging. Psychological terms for the apathy will refer to the cause (e.g. depression). Not only are you not providing any prior research information, which you will know [is required](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993), being you have some reputation in this SE site, this question needs narrowing down to be focused enough. Also, for psychological terminology questions, please bear https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2374 in mind.